# Unable to get file stream on Xiaomi

Tags: android, android-intent

I've build a blogger client where you can pick photos from gallery to embed on blog posts.

For some reason it doesn't work on Xiaomi phones on the majority of phones it works.

I'm picking files from gallery this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("image/*");
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

I'm using the following to load the pictures after selection:

```
String imagePath=data.getData().ToString();
Uri fileURI = Uri.parse(imagePath);
 try {
      fileInputStream = ((Context)mView).getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileURI);
 } catch (Exception e) {
/* Send logs to analyse later */
 }
```

Which results on the following error on some phones

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/FILE_NAME.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java)
```

I'm only letting the user try to pick files after receiving permission on Marshmallow+ versions, so it's not a permission issue.

It works on 95 ish % of users so this is something very specific.
Tried to reproduce the issue on 4.2, 4.4, 5.0.2, 7.0.2 on LG G2, Huawei Nova, Nexus 7 and emulator images, i was unable to reproduce it.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: `Uri fileURI = Uri.parse(imagePath);`?? imagePath? You do not get such if you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: Sorry, forget the rest of the code.

Comment: That did not matter anymore as nearly an hour ago i gave you an answer how you could do better. You could have reacted on my answer meanwhile.

Comment: I'll try it and if it works, i'll mark your answer as accepted. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In onActivityResult() use

```
  InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Do not try to find a file.

Use the input stream as if it were the file input stream.